# How to get list form txt file (Python)

Tags: python

everyone!

I have a simple txt file, with few number in a row (',' is separator)

"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21"

and this code:

```
num=[]
f = open('sample.txt','r')

for i in f:
    num.append(i.split(',')
print(num)
```

my goal is to get list of items:

```
['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21']
```

but i get list i list with 1 item:

```
[['1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21']]
```

looking for help

Comment: `num.extend(i.split(','))`

Comment: ty but result is ['1,2,3,..,n']
still 1 item in list

Comment: for i in f.split(‘,’)  num.append(i) ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have one line in your file, you don't need to loop over lines. You can assign `num` directly:

```
with open('sample.txt','r') as f:
    num = f.read().split(',')
```

Comment: Nice, it's work! But can u explain about '*'?

Comment: The '*' was a parameter unpacking to turn the map(int,...  back into a list.  I removed it when I realized your expected output was a list of strings (I initially thought you needed integers).

Answer (score 1):

```
This code will work even if you have multiple line to read


num=[]
f=open('input.txt')

for i in f:
    for j in (i.split(',')):
        num.append(j.replace('\n',''))
        
print(num)
```

**Explanation line by line steps**

1.creating empty list

2.opening file

3.Taking one element from f at a time

4.splitting i which returns list and than taking one item from list as j

5.appending j and if there is newline character in j, than remove \n (this happens when we have to read more than on line)

Answer (score 0):

Use extend, instead of append.
[What is the difference between Python's list methods append and extend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/what-is-the-difference-between-pythons-list-methods-append-and-extend)

```
  num=[]
    f = open('sample.txt','r')
    
    for i in f:
        num.extend(i.split(','))
    print(num)
```